# How can I check whether a state is existed globally in Corda?

Tags: corda

I have a state with a global ID. I want to check whether the state is already issued by other node before I issue the state.

Is there a way I can check the state on the whole chain or I have to notify all of the nodes about issuing new state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corda's privacy model means that there is no central "chain" that can be checked for an existing state with the same ID.

If you simply need a unique ID for your state, use something like `UniqueIdentifier`, ideally by implementing the `LinearState` interface (https://docs.corda.net/api-states.html#linearstate). `UniqueIdentifier` contains a 128-bit unique identifier. This is large enough to avoid collisions between all the `LinearState`s on the network, despite there being no centralised repository of allocated IDs.

If this is not good enough, and the IDs have to be allocated based on some scheme instead of randomly, you'll need to create some centralised oracle node that tracks issued IDs and only signs transactions where the ID being allocated has not been used before.